Mat-dialog pops up sporadically when switching components
I am pretty new to angular and its concepts. I have a problem, which I guess is somehow related to cleanup of subscriptions.
I have this confirmation dialog component:
export class ConfirmDialogComponent {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  confirmButtonText: string;
  cancelButtonText: string;
  errorMessage: string | null = null;
  isLoading = false;

  @Output() confirmAction = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: ConfirmDialogData,
    private translocoService: TranslocoService
  ) {
    const action = data.action || 'delete';
    const translatedType = this.translocoService.translate(data.type);

    this.title = this.translocoService.translate(`confirmation-dialog.${action}.title`, { name: translatedType });

    if (data.resource) {
      this.message = this.translocoService.translate(`confirmation-dialog.${action}.message`, { name: data.resource });
    } else {
      this.message = this.translocoService.translate('confirmation-dialog.default-message');
    }
    this.confirmButtonText = this.translocoService.translate('confirmation-dialog.confirm-button');
    this.cancelButtonText = this.translocoService.translate('confirmation-dialog.cancel-button');
  }

  onConfirmClick(): void {
    this.confirmAction.emit();
  }
}

Then in another component I use it to delete e.g. a member:
deleteMember(orgMemberResponseDto: OrganizationMemberResponseDto): void {
    this.authService.user$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe(user => {
      if (orgMemberResponseDto.userId === user?.sub) {
        this.confirmSelfDeletion(orgMemberResponseDto);
      } else {
        this.confirmMemberDeletion(orgMemberResponseDto);
      }
    });
  }


  private confirmMemberDeletion(orgMemberDto: OrganizationMemberResponseDto): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      disableClose: true,
      closeOnNavigation: true,
      data: {
        type: 'confirmation-dialog.type.organization-member',
        resource: orgMemberDto.firstName + ' ' + orgMemberDto.lastName
      }
    });

    dialogRef.componentInstance.confirmAction.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.deleteApiCall(orgMemberDto.userId, false);
        dialogRef.close(true);
      },
      error: (error: ApiError) => {
        if (dialogRef.componentInstance) {
          dialogRef.componentInstance.errorMessage = error.details;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private deleteApiCall(orgMemberId: string, isSelfDelete: boolean): void {
    this.organizationService.removeMemberOfCurrentOrganization(orgMemberId).pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)).subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.loadOrgMembers();
          if (isSelfDelete) {
            this.authService.logout();
          }
        },
        error: (error: ApiError) => {
          this.loadOrgMembers();
          this.snackbar.open(error.details || 'Cannot delete member', 'Close', {
            panelClass: 'mat-snack-bar-container',
            duration: 5000,
          });
        }
      })
  }

When I open and close the dialog, then switch to another component (via my navbar) sometimes the dialog pops up again in the new component. I cannot really reproduce it but it does happen sporadically. I had a hunch that its somehow related to unsubscribing, but the takeUntilDestroyed did not solve it yet.
